bash: Converting date-time into seconds and then back to date-time
In a bash script which converts timestamps into seconds, adds some seconds and converts the result back into a timestamp I get a bad result from the date command. This is the cause:
$ dt=$(date '+%s' -u --date="2024-11-25 20:31:00")
$ echo $dt
1732566660
$ date '+%F %T' -u --date="$dt seconds"
2079-10-21 22:33:33

What am I doing wrong?

To provide a Unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) as the input to date, prefix it with @:
$ TZ=UTC date -d @1732566660
Mon 25 Nov 20:31:00 UTC 2024

To see what date actually did with your input, use --debug, which will tell you that it understood the "n seconds" as meaning "+n seconds from now":
$ date '+%F %T' -u --date="$dt seconds" --debug       
date: parsed relative part: +1732566660 seconds
date: input timezone: TZ="UTC0" environment value or -u
date: using current time as starting value: '03:48:36'
date: using current date as starting value: '(Y-M-D) 2024-11-26'
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2024-11-26 03:48:36'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2024-11-26 03:48:36' = 1732592916 epoch-seconds
date: after time adjustment (+0 hours, +0 minutes, +1732566660 seconds, +0 ns),date:     new time = 3465159576 epoch-seconds
date: timezone: Universal Time
date: final: 3465159576.849887587 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2079-10-22 00:19:36 (UTC)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2079-10-22 00:19:36 (UTC+00)
date: output format: ‘%F %T’
2079-10-22 00:19:36

